# Aggregating data in DynamoDB that fits our access pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am currently trying to aggregate accelerometer data as it is loaded to our dynamo table. I would like to aggregate in 5 minute time windows on a per-user basis and insert the aggregation result into another dynamo table. Because I am not super well versed in Dynamo or Lambda, I am hoping someone can steer me in a different direction if I'm overlooking better solutions.

I am thinking the best way to do this would be to leverage DynamoDB Streams and have a Lambda that works on the data, aggregating it as it comes in so we don't have to query the DynamoDB table across every user every 5 minutes. The latter certainly keeps the Lambda simpler, but I assume that will take a substantial chunk out of our read capacity and will also cause Lambda execution times to be longer.

So, my idea is to process the stream inside a lambda that is triggered every 1000 records, and have it upsert a record in the new table on a per user basis for each 5 minute time window throughout the day, starting with midnight as time 0. The record will be inserted if none exists for the user for that time window. If a record does exist, it will conditionally update the aggregation.

The table will consist of a user id which is the partition key, in the format <\company id>|<\user id>, a window start time (<\date> 00:00, 00:05, 00:10, etc) which will be the sort key, a sum of the data i'm aggregating, and a count of the number of records used to calculate that sum, and an average.

With this structure, I believe can then pull data out on a per user basis for a particular company over a time range that I specify in my query.

Does this seem like a proper way of solving data aggregations with Dynamo? Is there anything I need to look out for both from a lambda perspective or a streams perspective that could cause scalability issues or query issues based on the structure I have outlined above?

Thanks!

Comment: Publishing custom metrics to CloudWatch Metrics might be a more appropriate solution: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html

Comment: Ah, I should have been more clear. This aggregated data will then be displayed on a webpage to the end user based on various filter conditions. Is cloudwatch still the place for this?

Comment: Yes, you can query CloudWatch Metrics, and you can potentially embed dashboards into your websites (see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-an-amazon-cloudwatch-dashboard-outside-of-the-aws-management-console/)

Answer (score 1):

Few things to note here.

<strike>I assume that will take a substantial chunk out of our read capacity and will also cause Lambda execution times to be longer.</strike> 
Dynamodb stream consists of both old and new data, hence you will not go to dyanamodb to fetch data. Hence no extra capacity consumption.

For the above problem you have database schema like this

```
|PK       |  SK             | timesegment    |
|mike     | event#12334     | 12330#12330    | some metadata about this event.
|mike     | event#12336     | 12335#12340    | some metadata about this event.
|mike     | metadata        |                | some metadata about mike completely optional
|tim      | event#12339     | 12335#12340    | some metadata about this event.
```

Where PK is userid, SK is information about the row.

Now there are two problems at hand

1. Where to store aggregation?

   You can choose either or dynamodb or cloudwatch whichever suits your need more.
2. How to calculate aggregation?

   For running aggregation, you need the following

   1. What all users changed in last 5 mins (because obviously we are not going to do a table scan.)

      There are multiple ways to answer this question,

      a. Have a GSI on the 5 min epoch time. Get all the PK's from this GSI table to know what all users changed. Now you can iterate over all the users to aggregate their data.

      Pros

      - You have all the data in one table, if something goes wrong, you can practically replay everything. this won't be possible while using streams.

      Cons

      - GSI would be very hot since for 5 mins time interval all the writes will be going to one partition only.

      b. While writing to dynamodb store the user info in another table so that we don't have to use GSI to fetch user list.

      Pros

      - There will not be any hot partition.

      Cons

      - Replay functionality won't be easily possible.
3. How to run aggregation

   Rather than having dynamodb stream, you can have a cloudwatch event triggering a lambda function which does the aggregation, if you see that lambda is timing out(aggregations are taking more than 15 mins), you can create one parent lambda function who just calculates the PKs that changed and puts it to SQS. then there is a lambda function subscribed to SQS, who does the calculation for every userid

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. This makes sense and I'll take it all into consideration. Also, just to be clear, I was referring to having my lambda wake up every 5 minutes and query the table to get data from the last 5 minutes rather than reading from a stream. So that is why I mentioned it counting against our read capacity. You are right though, I could wake up every 5 minutes and process the stream itself, which is another perfectly valid solution I didn't consider.

Comment: @gfree I don't think waking up kind of functionality is possible in the case of dynamodb streams, because we don't control  stream invoking lambda. When event comes lambda gets fired. It is not like sqs where you wakeup and readup all the events. while considering `stream vs trigger` you can evaluate lambda invocation cost. If your events are too many IMO trigger will cost you less. Since you are processing all the events for one user(going forward may be group of users) in one go but in case of stream it will always be one event in one lambda. hence cost wise trigger might make more sense

Comment: I sort of proved the concept with a cloud watch trigger every 5 minutes and writing my custom code to read from the stream using the KCL in a jar I uploaded. But, seemed way too convoluted and I would have had to manage too much myself. 

Can you describe more about "stream vs trigger?" What are you referencing here when you say stream?

FWIW I got this working for now by having my lambda trigger every 1000 records, reading the user's existing metadata, recalculating it with the new incoming data, then updating the record.

Comment: But, I'm still looking at potential other ways to solve this. When new records come in for a particular user and time period, I don't particularly like having to query my existing record to get the current average then recalculate with the new data. I don't like this because the query has an associated time in my lambda and associated dynamodb cost since I'm reading from the table before every update.

Comment: @gfree by stream i meant dynamodb stream, and by trigger cloudwatch trigger. When you setup dynamodb stream as a lambda invoker you will get both old and new record in the event. let's say there were 10^6 events in dyanmodb for 10^4 users, your cost will include 10^6 lambda execution and 10^6 aggregation table writes. but if you use cloudwatch trigger and keep a track of what changed in last 5 mins, you can invoke the lambda from cloudwatch trigger and process only for the users that changed. it would mean 10^4 gets from table, 10^4 puts to aggregation table and 10^4 lambda invocation.